# Is it possible to use apollo-android v2 with Gradle 5?

Tags: gradle, apollo, apollo-client, apollo-android

[The docs for v2 say that](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/android/essentials/migration/#migrating-to-2x)

> Gradle 6.x recommended. In 5.x, Gradle Metadata needs to be enabled by
> putting this into settings.gradle
> enableFeaturePreview("GRADLE_METADATA")

Which says that 6.x is just recommended, but when I try to use Gradle 5 I get the error

```
apollo-android requires Gradle version 6.0 or greater
```

Is there a workaround for this? Upgrading to Gradle 6 is not an option for my project right now.

[Here is the change](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android/commit/c5fee8e015ec18fd4e56510fe49c23cccf0add44#diff-bf25993eb69e5ccf9c0a98ed2a93eaf8R17) in apollo that bumps the minimum required Gradle version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I opened a [Github Issue](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android/issues/2536) with the apollo-android team and they've merged a fix to remove the Gradle 6 requirement. They've [dropped the requirement down to 5.6](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android/pull/2539/commits) though the fix has yet to be merged into a release. Should be available in the next release after v2.3.1.